# 'rich-voice-editor': true //not working using npm package: quill-rich-voice-editor

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ssml

I'm using this npm package in angular.

```
"quill": "^1.3.6",
"quill-rich-voice-editor": "^0.4.0",
```

If I add this line  `'rich-voice-editor': true`. It gives the error `core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: moduleClass is not a constructor`

Here is the code:

```
const quill = new Quill(this.richTextEditor.nativeElement, {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    toolbar: ssmlToolbarOptions,
    'rich-voice-editor': true // Add this.
  },
  placeholder: '<speak>Your text here</speak>',
});
```

**Error**:

[image]

If I remove `'rich-voice-editor': true`, it reacts like this.

**Frontend**:

[image]

I guess 'rich-voice-editor' module is missing

[image]

**rich-voice-editor URLs**:
[Github](https://github.com/fabiancelik/rich-voice-editor)
[Demo](https://fabiancelik.github.io/rich-voice-editor/)